# Df -h stuck on solaris. How to stop it?

Tags: unix, solaris, opensolaris

please help. I've got stuck when i type df -h [df stuck image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcky2.png)

i'm try press ctrl + c and ctrl + z but not working . My os is solaris 11

Comment: open a second ssh session and kill the process of the first one which is stuck.  Use `kill -9 process_code` . the process code you can get it using `ps`

Comment: Run `$pkill df` must kill that process.

Comment: the problem is server can't open ssh session. I connect via serial console.. will this process autimatically terminate ?

Answer (score 2):

My guess here is that you are running a version 3 NFS connection and on Solaris 11 you should be running version 4. One of the defects of version 3 was that it would hang the system on something like a df because the NFS would never return a result. I have seen system failures over this.

As has been suggested you will need to terminate the process and then look at the mounts. You can reset the serial connection and then deal with your underlying issue.

Comment: *One of the defects of version 3 was that it would hang the system*  A very good reason to always have a `.hushlogin` file in your home directory to suppress quota checks for all mounted filesystems.  Or you could go and remove `/usr/sbin/quota` from `/etc/profile`.